# How to handle mongoose connection error in try catch block?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, try-catch

how to handle mongoose connection error in try catch block?. I want to use application db connection with async function.

```
class App {
  async dbconnect() {
    try {
      mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.2/test");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(errror);
      process.exit(1);
    }

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState == 2) {
      console.log("Db Connected");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add `await`, plus you don't need to check the readyState. When the connection is failed, it will be automatically captured by the catch block of the `try-catch` system.
So your code block will be

```
class App {
  async dbconnect() {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.2/test"); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
    }

  }
}
```